# Generate slug and meta data if meta field is empty

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, slug, wp-insert-post, save-post

I am creating a current vacancies feature in a client site, and am struggling on one area.  I want to have a slug generated from a reference number, rather than the post title.  This, I have set up.  However, if a reference number is not entered, I want for Wordpress to generate a reference from `dechex(time())`.  I then want for that generated reference to become the slug, **but only if the meta field is empty**.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
add_action('save_post', 'ocp_jobs_save_details');
function ocp_jobs_save_details(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "ocp_jobs_ref", $post->post_name);
  // Other update_post_meta functions for other meta fields
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'ocp_jobs_slug' );
function ocp_jobs_slug( $data ) {
    if( 'job' == $data['post_type'] ) {
      if ( $_POST['ocp_jobs_ref'] ) { $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $_POST['ocp_jobs_ref'] ); }
      else { $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( dechex( time() ) ); }
    } else { }
    return $data;
}
```

Up to now, I have the following:

1. My `dechex(time())` reference number is being generated.
2. My generated number is being added to `post_name`.
3. When posted / updated, the generated reference number is inserted into the meta field.

What *isn't* happening, however, is the `ocp_jobs_ref` reference is not taking priority over the `dechex(time())` reference.  The generated number should only be used if I don't enter a reference number manually.  I gather that the `wp_insert_post_data` hook works before I even publish, so the reference number is generated and added automatically, rendering the submitted number redundant.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a little playtime, here is the answer:

```
add_action('save_post', 'ocp_jobs_save_details');
function ocp_jobs_save_details(){
  global $post;
  $genref = sanitize_title( dechex( time() ) );
  if ( $post->post_type == 'job' ) {
    if ( $_POST['ocp_jobs_ref'] ) { $jobs_args = array( 'ID' => $post->ID, 'post_name' => strtolower( sanitize_title( $_POST['ocp_jobs_ref'] ) ) ); $myref = strtoupper( $_POST['ocp_jobs_ref'] ); }
    else{ $jobs_args = array( 'ID' => $post->ID, 'post_name' => strtolower( $genref ) ); $myref = strtoupper( $genref ); }
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post->ID ) ){
        remove_action('save_post', 'ocp_jobs_save_details');
        wp_update_post( $jobs_args );
        add_action('save_post', 'ocp_jobs_save_details');
    }
  }
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "ocp_jobs_ref", $myref);
  // Other update_post_meta functions
}
```

The `wp_insert_post_data` filter isn't needed at all.  It probably isn't pretty or elegant, but it works.